# How to prevent a dialog from closing when a item is selected

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I have a dialog with items:

```
final String[] items = new String[] { "item1", "item2" };

AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Title");
adb.setCancelable(false);
adb.setItems(items, new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int n) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, items[n], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });
}

AlertDialog alert = adb.create();
alert.setCancelable(false);
alert.show();
```

When a item is selected, the `Toast` is shown and the dialog closes. How can I disable this?
I want that the dialog still remains open after a item is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `AlertDialog.Builder.setItems()` method which dismisses a dialog when an item is clicked.

In order to display a list of items and not have the dialog dismissed, you should use one of the overloads of [`setSingleChoiceItems()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) method:

> Set a list of items to be displayed in the dialog as the content, you will be notified of the selected item via the supplied listener. The list will have a check mark displayed to the right of the text for the checked item. **Clicking on an item in the list will not dismiss the dialog. Clicking on a button will dismiss the dialog.**

Comment: Is there a way to just provide a list, get notified onClick but dont dismiss the dialog? From what I understood of "setSingleChoiceItems" there will be a check mark beside..

Comment: Please check my solution below which does what was requested.

Answer (score 4):

Set the second parameter in the setItems method to null and attach an item listener to the listview that is part of the dialog:

```
var alertDialog: AlertDialog? = null
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!, R.style.alertDialogTheme)
    .setItems(items.toTypedArray(), null)
    .setTitle("My Dialog Title")
    .setPositiveButton(
        "OK"
    ) { dialog, id ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }.setNegativeButton(
        "Cancel"
    ) { dialog, id ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

alertDialog = builder.show()
alertDialog.listView.setOnItemClickListener(object: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    override fun onItemClick(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        // Do something with item click.
    }
})
alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods I use. The first one is the easiest, The second one is the same as the above @AndroidDev's answer.

**First One**

```
builder.setItems(items, (dialogInterface, n) -> {
        if(n == 0){
            builder.show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, items[n], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

**Second One:**
(Same as the above one but here as the Java8 lambda)

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getListView().setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, subview, i, l)->{

    });
```